# facebook SDK incorrect ids being supplied using the getUser method in different locations of zend 1 framework application

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, zend-framework, facebook-sdk-3.0

I am having difficulty with facebook user ids in our system. After retrieving the information via the facebook api method `getUser()`, i cannot obtain that id from any subsequent calls to `getUser()`.

Here is the registration code that redirects the user to the facebook login:

```
    $this->view->layout ()->disableLayout ();
    $this->_helper->viewRenderer->setNoRender ( true );
    $appId = Ranger_Application_Util::getConfig('facebook_app_id');
    $appSecret = Ranger_Application_Util::getConfig('facebook_app_secret');
    require_once 'facebook/src/facebook.php';
    $facebook = new Facebook(array(
            'appId' => $appId,
            'secret' => $appSecret,
            'cookie' => true
    ));
    $args = array();
    $args['redirect_uri'] = 'http://url.com/en/account/callback-facebook';
    $url = $facebook->getLoginUrl($args);
    $redirector = Zend_Controller_Action_HelperBroker::getStaticHelper ( 'Redirector' );
    $redirector->gotoUrl ( $url )->redirectAndExit ();
```

Here is the redirect code:

```
    $this->view->layout ()->disableLayout ();
    $this->_helper->viewRenderer->setNoRender ( true );
    $appId = Ranger_Application_Util::getConfig('facebook_app_id');
    $appSecret = Ranger_Application_Util::getConfig('facebook_app_secret');
    require_once 'facebook/src/facebook.php';
    $facebook = new Facebook(array(
            'appId' => $appId,
            'secret' => $appSecret,
            'cookie' => true
    ));     
    $accessToken = $facebook->getAccessToken();     
    $mdl = new Core_Model_Resource_Users();
    $user = $facebook->getUser();       
    if($user){
        try {
            $profile = $facebook->api('/me');               
            $newUserId = $mdl->insert(array(
                    'fuid' => $user,
                    'facebook_access_token' => $accessToken,
                    'first_name' => $profile['first_name'],
                    'middle_name' => $profile['middle_name'],
                    'last_name' => $profile['last_name'],
                    'status' => 'active',
                    'verified' => 1,
                    'hash' => Ranger_Application_Util::generateHash(),
                    'acl_role' => 'client',
                    'avatar' => 'default.png',
                    'date_created' => new Zend_Db_Expr("NOW()"),
                    'date_updated' => new Zend_Db_Expr("NOW()"),
                    'username' => 'user'.Ranger_Application_Util::generateHash()
            ));
        } catch(Exception $e){
            echo "Issue getting user information. ".$e->getMessage();
            die();
        }
    } else {
        echo "Issue getting user information";
        die();
    }
```

Now here is my **zend plugin** that **detects facebook for usage of automatic sign in**. This should only activate after the callback.

```
    public function preDispatch(Zend_Controller_Request_Abstract $request) {
        $appId = Ranger_Application_Util::getConfig('facebook_app_id');
        $appSecret = Ranger_Application_Util::getConfig('facebook_app_secret');
        require_once 'facebook/src/facebook.php';
        $facebook = new Facebook(array(
               'appId' => $appId,
               'secret' => $appSecret,
               'cookie' => true
        ));
        $user = $facebook->getUser();
        if($user){
            $fetchMode = Core::db()->getFetchMode();
            Core::db()->setFetchMode(Zend_Db::FETCH_OBJ);
            $userProfile = $facebook->api('/me');
            $mdl = new Core_Model_Resource_Users();
            $sel = $mdl->select();
            $sel->where('fuid=:fuid')->bind(array(":fuid"=>$user));
(OR:)       $sel->where('fuid=:fuid')->bind(array(":fuid"=>$userProfile['id']));
            $data = $mdl->fetchRow($sel);
            Core::db()->setFetchMode($fetchMode);
            Ranger_Application_Util::logUserIn($data->id);
      }
```

No matter how many times I do the following:

- clean out cookies and history
- use the `$facebook->destroySession()` method

Here is the MySQL Information:

```
FUID -> INT(30)
FACEBOOK_ACCESS_TOKEN -> VARCHAR(255)
```

Its still supplying me with two different IDs from `$user` on the **detect portion of code** Furthermore, it looks like the IDs are only inequal when using the detect code.

Any ideas what I should be doing?

Comment: Which variable contains 2 different ids? And can you give an example of them?

Comment: In the redirect code I use `$user` to obtain the user id and then i redirect back to the app and the preDispatch method then uses the `$user` variable which should give me the same id as the one from the redirect code.

Comment: Are you sure the code portions use the same app id? And, is your app v1.0 or v2.0?

Comment: How are you testing that both the functions are returning different ids ? Also can you share the users table structure ?

Comment: What data, if any, is being received from each `getUser()` call?

Comment: @Qoop the `getUser()` method is a standard Facebook SDK method.

Comment: @SyedQarib I added the table column information

Comment: FYI: You should not be storing Facebook user ids as integers – they _are not_ integers. Use a text data type.

Comment: @CBroe I bet thats the answer. Ill try this out

Comment: Yeah, I asked what you are getting from `getUser()`, as in what id's.

Comment: I'm confused `$facebook` is the Facebook php SKD yes? if so why are you using that for the id if you want the users id your better off getting it from the `$facebook->api('me')->id` if the user is logged in thats all you need to use if thats there they have an active facebook session on your site if not there is no session active so you can auto log them in when its there if it not dont

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should not be using 2 different ways to get your user id stick with one and the Graph API is the recommended one. `$p = $facebook->api("/me"); $p['id']`

Redirect code:

```
$this->view->layout ()->disableLayout ();
    $this->_helper->viewRenderer->setNoRender ( true );
    $appId = Ranger_Application_Util::getConfig('facebook_app_id');
    $appSecret = Ranger_Application_Util::getConfig('facebook_app_secret');
    require_once 'facebook/src/facebook.php';
    $facebook = new Facebook(array(
            'appId' => $appId,
            'secret' => $appSecret,
            'cookie' => true
    ));     
    $accessToken = $facebook->getAccessToken();     
    $mdl = new Core_Model_Resource_Users();
    $user = $facebook->getUser();       
    if($user){
        try {
            $profile = $facebook->api('/me');               
            $newUserId = $mdl->insert(array(
                    'fuid' => $profile["id"],
                    'facebook_access_token' => $accessToken,
                    'first_name' => $profile['first_name'],
                    'middle_name' => $profile['middle_name'],
                    'last_name' => $profile['last_name'],
                    'status' => 'active',
                    'verified' => 1,
                    'hash' => Ranger_Application_Util::generateHash(),
                    'acl_role' => 'client',
                    'avatar' => 'default.png',
                    'date_created' => new Zend_Db_Expr("NOW()"),
                    'date_updated' => new Zend_Db_Expr("NOW()"),
                    'username' => 'user'.Ranger_Application_Util::generateHash()
            ));
        } catch(Exception $e){
            echo "Issue getting user information. ".$e->getMessage();
            die();
        }
    } else {
        echo "Issue getting user information";
        die();
    }
```

again make sure that `fuid` column is set to a string type MySQL `varchar(200)` is what i use for facebook UIDs

```
public function preDispatch(Zend_Controller_Request_Abstract $request) {
        $appId = Ranger_Application_Util::getConfig('facebook_app_id');
        $appSecret = Ranger_Application_Util::getConfig('facebook_app_secret');
        require_once 'facebook/src/facebook.php';
        $facebook = new Facebook(array(
               'appId' => $appId,
               'secret' => $appSecret,
               'cookie' => true
        ));
        $user = $facebook->getUser();
        if($user){
            $fetchMode = Core::db()->getFetchMode();
            Core::db()->setFetchMode(Zend_Db::FETCH_OBJ);
            $userProfile = $facebook->api('/me');
            $mdl = new Core_Model_Resource_Users();
            $sel = $mdl->select();
            $sel->where('fuid='.$userProfile['id']);
            // i don't like bind for one variable php will be quicker  using string concatenation
            $data = $mdl->fetchRow($sel);
            Core::db()->setFetchMode($fetchMode);
            Ranger_Application_Util::logUserIn($data->id);
      }
```

Thats all you should be doing